# Generating permutations

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-3.x

I have an algorithm for generating permutations in Python

```
from collections import Counter

def permutations(A):
    def permutations(A):
        if len(A) == 0:
            return
        if len(A) == 1:
            yield A
        else:
            for i in range(1, len(A)):
                for p in permutations(A[i:]): # Pretend slicing is O(1)
                    for q in permutations(A[:i]): # Pretend slicing is O(1)
                        yield p + q # Pretend O(1)
                        yield q + p # Pretend O(1)
    return set(permutations(A))

P = permutations((1, 2, 3))
C = Counter(P)
print(P)
print(C)
```

Which has output

```
{(3, 1, 2), (1, 3, 2), (3, 2, 1), (2, 3, 1), (1, 2, 3), (2, 1, 3)}
Counter({(2, 1, 3): 1, (1, 3, 2): 1, (3, 1, 2): 1, (3, 2, 1): 1, (2, 3, 1): 1, (1, 2, 3): 1})
```

Assuming I don't care about the time it takes to slice/concatenate arrays, is this the most efficient algorithm for generating permutations? If not, what can I do to improve it?

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you have to use `set(...)` to deduplicate any time of combinatorial object, you probably don't have the most efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the obvious method would be to use the `itertools` module which has exactly what you want. [Here are the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), just in case you'll need to look up for something else.

```
from itertools import permutations


def generate_permutations():
    return list(permutations([1,2,3]))
```

The above will return:

> `[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]`

Below, you can find the algorith of this module:

```
def permutations(iterable, r=None):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(n)
    cycles = range(n, n-r, -1)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
                break
        else:
            return
```

As you can see, this is using just a while loop do do what you did in 3 separate `for` loops. For this kind of operations, I strongly recommend using the `itertools` module.